# how to create pagination for angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, mean-stack

Hi all i want to Pagination for the table. Pagination to create 10 set of row data one page another 10 set of row 2nd page using angular js. I tried many ways but unable to get the solution if anyone knows the solution please help me... 
Demo link is https://plnkr.co/edit/hT9fBUMWOBoOHHjba1Uo?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<td data-title="'S.No'" sortable="'s_no'" filter="{ 's_no': 'text' }">{{$index + 1}}</td>
             <td data-title="'Enquiry Received Date'" sortable="'enquiry_received_date'" filter="{ 'enquiry_received_date': 'text' }">{{sryarnenquiry.enquiry_received_date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
              <td data-title="'Count'" sortable="'description_count'" filter="{ 'description_count': 'text' }">{{sryarnenquiry.description_count}}</td>
              <td data-title="'Quality'" sortable="'description_quality'" filter="{ 'description_quality': 'text' }">{{sryarnenquiry.description_quality}}</td>
               <td data-title="'Quantity'"  sortable="'quantity'" filter="{ 'quantity': 'text' }">{{sryarnenquiry.quantity}} {{sryarnenquiry.quantity_unit}}</td>
                <td data-title="'Ex India Date'"  ng-hide="report" sortable="'ex_india_date'" filter="{ 'ex_india_date': 'text' }">{{sryarnenquiry.ex_india_date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                <td  data-title="'Supplier Name'"  sortable="'supplier_name'" filter="{ 'supplier_name': 'text' }">{{sryarnenquiry.supplier_name}}</td>
                 <td data-title="'Actual Devlivery Date'"  sortable="'actual_devlivery_date'" filter="{ 'actual_devlivery_date': 'text' }">{{sryarnenquiry.actual_devlivery_date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
```

**Data**

```
{
"_id": "5909d10ff00c1c9b0e84ab64",
"user": {
"_id": "584ad334f8c0f4a31fe65e68",
"displayName": "sunil kumar"
},
"description_count": "checking",
"description_quality": "new",
"__v": 0,
"created": "2017-05-03T12:46:07.569Z",
"cone": "-",
"status": "quoted",
"currency": "Rs",
"unit": "KG",
"price": [
"200"
],
"actual_devlivery_date": "2017-05-09",
"ex_india_date": "2017-05-03",
"quantity_unit": "KG",
"quantity": "32",
"enquiry_received_date": "2017-05-17",
"supplier_name": "karikalan",
"buyer_name": "Mani selvam"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use existing Angular directives to achieve this. I would recommend [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) (scroll to pagination for documentation) to do this. I created a a working example of your code in a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/em7Xv1XtzDumYQGg2Fbo?p=preview).

```
 <pagination 
    ng-model="currentPage"
    total-items="sryarnenquiries.length"
    max-size="maxSize"  
    items-per-page=itemsPerPage
    boundary-links="true">
</pagination>
```

The above code is for the pagination controls. In your controller i defined `$scope.itemsPerPage` which i set to 10 in your case. I also defined `$scope.currentPage = 1` in your controller, because otherwise it does not show any data.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Another question is table size 10 row and next page move to start with table s.no 1.2.3,.. My question is table serial number to change dynamically s.no 11, 12,..Pls help me...